# Android 3.2 and WifiManager.setWifiEnabled

Tags: java, android, wifi, android-wifi

I updated to Android 3.2 and now when I call `WifiManager.setWifiEnabled` I get an error in the log saying `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` permission needed.

Is this something that has changed with 3.2?
(Is this change documented somewhere?)

I would like to be able to disable Wifi from my app (most of the time) as its not needed and will only use more battery than necessary.
Is there a way to do disable Wifi from 3.2 onwards?

Regards
Jerry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WiFi power management is a system-wide setting and not the responsibility of your application. As long as you don't grab an explicit [WifiLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html) or power-hungry WakeLock (such as [FULL_WAKE_LOCK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#FULL_WAKE_LOCK)), then Android will respect the users power management choices and so should you.

If you still want to turn WiFi on and off, you need to make sure you have the [CHANGE_WIFI_STATE](http://android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE) permission.

I'm not sure why the log mentions WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS, but unless you are explicitly catching an exception thrown by setWifiEnabled that complains about it, then the message isn't for you.